# how do i stop duplicate information from being uploaded to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, function

i'm new to php, so go slow (please). I'm have my code set up to let users enter the URL of a youtube video and that video being put on one of the pages of the website. The only problem is that i cant figure out how to stop duplicate videos from being uploaded. A lot of the mysql code has been written by dreamwevaer. I've made several attempts to get it to stop duplicates but i think im missing something. So could someone give me instructions on how to add something that will stop multiple copies of the same thing being uploaded. THANKS.

Here is my code:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/Main.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_Main, $Main);
$query_youtube = "SELECT video_id FROM youtube";
$youtube = mysql_query($query_youtube, $Main) or die(mysql_error());
$row_youtube = mysql_fetch_assoc($youtube);
$totalRows_youtube = mysql_num_rows($youtube);

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

    $pieces = explode("=", $_POST['url']);
    $Ndone = $pieces[1];
    $pieces = explode("&", $Ndone);
    $done = $pieces[0];
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "youtube")) {

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO youtube (video_id) VALUES (%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($done, "text"));

  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $Main) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="../SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.text_box {
    text
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #000;
    }
</style>
<body>
  <?php 
if (isset($_POST['url'])){
    echo "YouTube Video Submited";
    }
?>
  <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="youtube" height="100px" method="POST" id="youtube">
    <span id="url">
    <input type="text" class="text_box" value="type in url of video " name="url" id="url2" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    </input>
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="youtube" />
    </p>
    </input>
  </form>
  <?php ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("url", "url", {validateOn:["blur"]});
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($youtube);
?>
```

Comment: there is nothing to do with PHP, you just need to define an unique index/key into your table schema. in your case, should be youtube URL, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html , i think the mysql doc will make you wanna cry ...

Comment: Meaning that you don't want, say, the same URL in the DB twice?

Answer (score 0):

Without reading through your entire block of code, the statement you are looking for is [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). The database column will have to be an index or primary key. If you try to insert it twice, it will perform an update instead of an insert.

Edit: On the PHP side of things, you might want to look into [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) and strip out all the unnecessary tags. Perhaps instead of storing the entire URL you should only be storing the actual unique identifier for the video. For example, instead of storing `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xqghpm4gXf4&feature=feedrec_grec_index`, just store `Xqghpm4gXf4` and then recompile the URL later from that string.

Comment: Thanks, the second part im already doing. I just forgot to say that in my comment. I'm wondering if there is a way to check on the php side if there is a duplicate, since i want to inform the user that the video has already been updated. Or can you do this with what your saying?

Comment: For that, just search whether it exists (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE video='$video' LIMIT 1`) and if `mysql_num_rows` == 1, then show the error, else do the insert.

Comment: For some reason the variable containing what the mysql gets contains "something resorce #4" every time, weather or not the thing exists already. So its always saying it exists already.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean and explain how you obtained the "something resource #4" text?

Comment: O, sorry. I used an echo statement. But i also checked how many rows were being returned each time on the mysql_num_rows(). function

Comment: but the function returns 1 no matter what the video url is.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I think i know what im doing wrong.